# How do I transfer an image from its URL to the SD card?

Tags: android, image, download, android-sdcard

How can I save an images to the SD card that I retrieve from the image's URL?

Comment: @Akusete... you should replace 'buffer.length' in output.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); to bytesRead. Otherwise garbage data will be appended at the end of the file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First you must make sure your application has permission to write to the sdcard. To do this you need to add the uses permission **write external storage** in your applications manifest file. See [Setting Android Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html)

Then you can you can download the URL to a file on the sdcard. A simple way is:

```
URL url = new URL ("file://some/path/anImage.png");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
try {
    //The sdcard directory e.g. '/sdcard' can be used directly, or 
    //more safely abstracted with getExternalStorageDirectory()
    File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (new File(storagePath,"myImage.png"));
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

**EDIT :**
Put permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: @Paresh: Thanks, I've updated the code to use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Do you know if it returns a trailing slash? e.g. `/sdcard` or `/sdcard/`

Comment: Your question is moot because `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` does not return a `String` and therefore your code does not compile.  I corrected your code for you.

Comment: aReasonableSize is a size that wont give you out of memory exceptions. Usually 1024 or 2048 will do.

Answer (score 8):

An excellent example can be found in the [latest post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) on Android developer's blog:

```
static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + 
               " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();  
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
        // IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url,
           e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't describe how to save the image to the sdcard, only how to download the image to memory.