# How to save files to SD card?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to store images from url & save it in SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/android-how-to-store-images-from-url-save-it-in-sd-card)

Hi....Im new to Android.....I dont know how to store the html report to SD Card and how to retrieve it. if u provide relevant code that will help me a lot.

Sry frnds.....Here is the link wat i found in google.
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-how-to-create-file-in-sd-card-part-1/

and can u tell me how to read the file and where can i found the file....?

Thanks in Advance

Ash

Comment: Please rephrase your question. If there's something specific you're having problems with, let us know, or are you just asking us to write code for you?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) or try [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=android+write+file+to+sd+card&btnG=Search)

Answer (score 0):

possible duplication [How do I transfer an image from its URL to the SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/android-how-to-store-images-from-url-save-it-in-sd-card)