# Can Android SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase() be used to open a remote sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to open a remote sqlite database with a url such as:

http://www.mysite.com/db.sqlite

Can I use SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase() for this?  If not, what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a file on the device or SD card.

[Official Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase)

Comment: what's the best way to download a large sqlite database to the device/SD card?

Comment: You can transfer it to your sd card using your pc. If you want to download it in your application you need to create a web service.  I use WCF Services using .NET programming.

Comment: I was hoping to just download the file from a URL and then access it locally.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/android-how-to-store-images-from-url-save-it-in-sd-card, maybe you could do the same thing with your database instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use it for remote sqllite database call. When your database is remote, you will end up making web service call to service hosted on your database server, which returns either XML/JSON formatted data.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking about it.  I don't think you can remotely query SQLite databases because they are just flat files, right?  Well, Ideally I'd like to download the database locally but it is large and I haven't found a great way to download it fast enough to keep the user from getting annoyed!

Comment: May be one way is keep populating local database as need basis.

Comment: @gonzobrains If it's possible to install a "baseline" database with the app, synchronizing it with the server may not take as long. But I guess that's not always an option.