# Is there any solution to pass image getting from url in multipart body

Tags: android, multipartform-data

```
path="https://www.example.com/sample.png"

File file = new File(path);


RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

This gives me error No such file or directory

I have image url and wanted to pass image in multipart

Comment: What you mean "multi part". can you explain clearly

Comment: it depend on end point.

Comment: Edited the code

Comment: First you need to save image. Then only you will get its physical path doing `File file = new File(path)` does not holds image path

Comment: @Mrinmoy How can I save image and get the physical path of the particular image, Can you help me?

Comment: refer following link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388793/5722385]

Comment: @Mrinmoy I dosen't worked.

Comment: @AviSoni File path must be local, not other. You path file is already uploaded in your example.png. It is not your local path its URL.

Comment: Your path must be like /storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170210_163055.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
  String urlString = "paste your image url here."
        String retString = "";
        try {

            String charset = "UTF-8";

            MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(
                    urlString, charset);

            multipart.addFormField("objid", objId);
            multipart.addFormField("createdby",
                    POPreferences.getUten(EditBpmActivity.this));
            multipart.addFormField("updatedby",                POPreferences.getUten(EditBpmActivity.this));
            multipart.addFormField("version",
                    "1");
            multipart.addFormField("objType",
                    fId);
            multipart.addFormField("isdeleted",
                    "3");
            multipart.addFilePart("Data", sourceFile);
            multipart.addFormField("Content-Type",getMimeType());
            List<String> response = multipart.finish();

            Log.v("rht", "SERVER REPLIED:");

            for (String line : response)
            {
                retString += line;
                Log.e("rht", "Line : " + line);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retString;
```

Comment: Are you okay? What the objId, fId, sourceFile varriables and so on??

Comment: hii  objid , fid is the another field which is used in my api for uploading image

Comment: I understand it is fields, obviously! need to specify it in the code! at least hardcode, don't show ununderstandable fields!