# How can I set my android app background from a server?

Tags: android, background, webserver, drawable, dynamically-generated

I'm quite new to android programming and I have the following problem.
I want to be able to put an image om my server and then if I use my app it should use that image as a background.
From previous research I understand I cant save any files to the drawable file?
So is this even possible?

I am now this far:

```
  URL url = new URL ("http://oranjelan.nl/oranjelan-bg.png");
  InputStream input = url.openStream();
  try { 
     String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath + "/oranjelangb.png");
     try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
     } finally {
      output.close();
        }
    } finally {
   input.close();
 }
```

But I get the following error 
@ String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
The compiller says cannot convert file to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible. Simple steps may include :-

1) Download image file from server, Store it to SDcard or assets folder.
  links for step 1 >>   [link1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)   [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/android-how-to-store-images-from-url-save-it-in-sd-card)

2) Create a Bitmap from the file you downloaded.

3) Set that bitmap as a Background image.

You can pick steps and search on SO there should be lots of answers available.

Comment: I'll be able to do steps 2 and 3 with the current knowledge I have. But I dont know how to save the file to the SD or Assets folder. Can u please explain to my how? And if I store an image to the SD card wont the user be prompted every time it tries to store it?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/android-how-to-store-images-from-url-save-it-in-sd-card

Comment: @Michiel T>> Fran Verona given an Excellent link for your question, I also edited my answer Please have a look.

Thanks FranVerona

Comment: Thanks alot guys, it has helped alot but I get an error if i try to apply the piece of code.

Comment: I cant vote up because I dont have the required rep yet. And it still doenst work yet. Please try to help!

Comment: @Michiel Good, you gone so far, Now Accept the answer and Post your code as a different question. I have solution for file to string problem. but can not post it here, As your original question already answered. If you post it as a different question that "error in storing downloaded file", the can able to answer there. Post link of new question here

Comment: Okee thanks, I've posted the "new" question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365043/how-to-get-an-png-to-an-android-phone-external-sd