# How to get an .png to an android phone (external_sd)

Tags: android, image, http

I have a problem trying to get a .png image to my android phone.
I am now this far:

```
URL url = new URL ("http://oranjelan.nl/oranjelan-bg.png");
  InputStream input = url.openStream();
  try { 
     String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath + "/oranjelangbg.png");
     try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
     } finally {
      output.close();
        }
    } finally {
   input.close();
 }
```

But I get the following error @ String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); The compiller says cannot convert file to string.

Then if i fool around a bit and try this piece of code:

```
URL url;

    void setup() {
    try {

        URL url = new URL ("http://oranjelan.nl/oranjelan-bg.png");
        InputStream input = url.openStream();{
        try {

            String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath + "/oranjelangbg.png");
                try {


byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    } finally {
            output.close();
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
   }    
 }    
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

then my android freezes when I launch the app.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Wow lots of replies many thanks for that in advance, i have to quit for now and will be back on monday, will reply and look into this then.

Comment: Try out downloading image in different thread. It will overcome Freezing issue..

Comment: Thanks alot guys, I think I get it now and all awnsers are good! and have helped me alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Tanis.7x pointed out, you will need to move the network operations out of the UI thread and into something such as an AyncTask.  Otherwise you will not be able to interact with the application until it finishes downloading - that may result in an application unresponsive message and a force close.  In more recent android versions, doing networking on the main thread is an automatic exception, even if it does not result in delay.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

It returns a File (java.io.File), not a String.

I use something along the lines of:

```
File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File outFile = new File(storagePath, filename + FILE_EXTENSION);
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

Comment: @Ankit - do not downvote accurate partial answers, unless they claim to be complete.  I could as easily downvote your answer for its huge omission, but won't.

Comment: I added a code example for clarification, but the original content of the message was still relevant and should have satisfactorily answered the question.

Comment: @Ankit - an answer does not have to be in the form of code, pointing out the precise problem is enough.

Comment: @Ankit - actually, concise answers which point out the precise problem are great.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
 File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/oranjelangb.png");
 OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath.getAbsoluteFile());
```